# Finding the range of $\frac{2x}{1 - 5x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the range of $\dfrac{2x}{1-5x}$.

I know the domain is $(-\infty,1/5) \cup (1/5,\infty)$. How would we find the range? It says the range is all numbers besides $-2/5$, but how do we know that or find it?

Comment: Have you tried to make a sketch of the graph, to at least convince yourself that the answer is reasonable?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site using MathJax.

Comment: A related problem is to find the *asymptotes* of a rational function.  Here a vertical asymptote corresponds to a value missing in the domain, while a horizontal asymptote corresponds to a value missing in the range.

Answer (score 4):

Set $y = \frac{2x}{1-5x}$.

Can you solve for $x$? If you can, then $y$ is in the range of the function. If you cannot, then $y$ is not in the range of the function.

Let's try it out by attempting to solve for $x$:
$$y(1-5x) = 2x
$$
$$y - 5xy = 2x
$$
$$y = 5xy + 2x
$$
$$y = (5y+2) x
$$
$$x = \frac{y}{5y+2}
$$
This always works no matter what $y$ is, *except* when $y=-\frac{2}{5}$. So, the range is all real numbers except $-\frac{2}{5}$.

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: So -2/5=2x/(1-5x)? Is this what u mean by setting it?

Comment: Because you can still solve for x with that

Comment: What he means is that $x$ is not defined for $y = -2/5$, if you plug in this value, you get a division by $0$.

Comment: @JuliusL33t ok thought so. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: @JuliusL33t How we would we know to test -2/5 tho? How do we know that is the value excluded ? Other than doing trial and error?

Comment: You know that $-2/5$ is excluded because you know that division by zero is excluded. So, ask yourself, what value of $y$ makes the denominator of the fraction $\frac{y}{5y+2}$ equal to zero?

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand slighty on Lee Moshers answer:

When you are solving your equation for $x$, what you are essentially doing is finding the inverse of the function. So if you want some function output, maybe say $y = y_0$, then the formula
$$x = \frac{y}{5y+2} $$
will produce the $x$ that you need for your chosen function output $y_0$.

As you can see, you can produce an $x$ for any value of $y$ except $y = -\frac{2}{5}$

Therefore the range is all the real numbers except $-\frac{2}{5}$

Comment: Ok so when u input -2/5 into the “x=y/(5y+2) you get a zero on the denominator and considering you cant divide by zero the output -2/5 is excluded ? Correct?

Comment: It sounds good. Note that this means that there is no $x$ for which $y = -2/5$. This is precisely what it means for $-2/5$ to be excluded from the range.

Comment: But for any other value of $y$, you can use the formula above to get the $x$ you need to plug in to get your value of $y$.

Comment: okay, how would we know tho to test -2/5? Besides trial and error to see what value gives us zero in the denominator?

Comment: well you could put the denominator to $0$ and solve the equation $5y + 2 = 0$. The solution is $y = -2/5$

Comment: Great, thank you! I appreciate your clarity.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)